# Animação em VueJs igual em JQuery

Tags: jquery, vue.js

Eu uso um código em jQuery pra fazer uma animação de carregamento da página, como faço o mesmo com VueJs?

```
(function ($) {
      "use strict";
      (function ($) {
        "use strict";
        var uza_window = $(window);
        uza_window.on("load", function () {
          $("#preloader").fadeOut("1000", function () {
            $(this).remove();
          });
        });
      })(jQuery);
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: seria algo assim? https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

Comment: https://codepen.io/rovalx/pen/aOEXPG

Comment: tipo isso do link

Comment: mas queria saber se há algo nativo do vuejs pra fazer, eu sei com js

Comment: Se o que vc quer é um loader que inicialize com a página e depois de certo tempo suma da tela, não tem nada nativo no Vue, você terá que implementar por conta ou usar um framework css tipo Vuetify que já vem com essas funcionalidades como essas de loading: https://vuetifyjs.com/pt-BR/components/progress

Comment: Então de todo jeito vou ter que usar o jquery, aparentemente, pra saber qual a hora certa de parar

Comment: Cara se você está utilizando Vue não tem a menor necessidade de utilizar jQuery. Existem várias formas de fazer isso, uma delas é com **setTimeout()**.

Comment: Mas o setTimeout apenas vai definir um timer, e não o tempo exato de carregamento, eu fiz com vue usando setTimeout, porém só aparece a animação quando carrega a página, e não no carregamento

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode utilizar os estados do [ciclo de vida da instância vue](https://br.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Ciclo-de-Vida-da-Instancia) para manter um componetente do loading visível como no exemplo abaixo.

Quando sua página for carregada ela irá invocar o método `mounted`, nele você pode definir que o componente loading pode ser escondido.

```js
Vue.component("loading", {
  template: "<div v-if=\"isLoading\">Carregando...</div>",
  props: ["isLoading"],
})

Vue.component("my-page", {
  template: `
    <div>
      <loading :is-loading="!loaded"/>
      <div v-if="loaded">
      Olá mundo!
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  data() {
    return {
      loaded: false
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    let self = this
    setTimeout(function() {
      self.loaded = true
    }, 3000)
  }
})


new Vue({
  el: "#app"
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <my-page/>
</div>
```